# Java - Go To Non-Static Void From Static Void?

Tags: java, class, methods, static

Well as my code doesn't really help very much, I wont show any unless someone needs to see some.

But I'll give an example of what I want to do.

Example: "Class1.java"

```
class Class1 {

    int num = 3 + 2;

    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        Class2.Main2();
    }
}
```

Example: "Class2.java"

```
class Class2 {

    public void Main2() {
        System.out.println(Class1.num);    // Would return as an error, as you cannot access static objects from non-static objects/methods.
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to allow going from one static method to another non-static method, or vice versa?

Thanks.

Comment: This is elementary knowledge that is way too broad to be handled here on SO. Get yourself a good book or some relevant tutorials to learn this. You can get started here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/

Comment: You can access static from non-static, it's the other way around, and for good reasons.

Comment: The error will show in `Main(String[] args)` method, too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello before i answer your question i would to tell you need to learn [java OPP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/) ( Object-Oriented Programming )

I dont know why you want to call an instance from class2 then call it again from class1, anyway here is the answer

Class1.java

```
class Class1 {
    int num = 3 + 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class2 obj = new Class2(); //creating an object of Class2

        obj.Main2();
    }
}
```

Class2.java

```
 class Class2 {
        public void Main2() {
            Class1 mnum = new Class1(); //creating an object of Class1
            System.out.println(mnum.num);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not literally doing that in my code, though. I was working on an Operating System and I didn't want to work around it. Just had to figure out the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Create an instance of Class2 and then call the main using the instance as in

new Class2().Main2();